# Internet doesn't work over Wifi hotspot

Tags: internet, oneplus

I am using OnePlus 3T with 4G. Internet works fine on the phone but when I connect a laptop or other phone to the phone using Wifi hotspot internet doesn't work at all. It used to work fine earlier.
I have tried the following:

1. Change the name, password and AP Bands between 2.4 GHz & 5 GHz in the hotspot settings.
2. Deleted the saved info from connected devices and re-enter.
3. Contacted my TSP. According to them its outside their scope. Later tried with a different network service provider but still didn't work. So issue is definitely with the phone.
4. Bluetooth Tethering works.
5. From the other phone, Wifi hotspot works fine on the laptop. the other phone is an iPhone if it's relevant.
6. Wifi on the phone works fine.

I can't think of any other way to troubleshoot. I don't want to format or factory reset my phone. What's the solution here?

*Additional info: Android Version 9, OxygenOS version 9.0.6*

Comment: Have you tried to give the pc and other phone static IP addresses?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I want to know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Check if setting static IP addresses might solve the problem or not.

Comment: In Settings>Developer Options, turned off the Tethering Hardware acceleration. It worked.